# Android Settings project

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to setup an android Settings project on eclipse. I got it from the tablet manufaturer. So I need to setup that project on eclipse and need to make some changes to the settings. When I get this project into eclipse then i am getting some compilation errors as follows:

```
code is looking for this class android.os.SystemProperties,R.xml.accessibilitySettings
```

Please let me know how to compile this project properly.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

If you get errors like this, press Ctrl+ Shift + O in order to update the packages automatically.

Sometimes, you might have to add strings in res directory, in separate xml file called strings.xml

Try running simple examples from android samples package for better understanding

Comment: thanks for your response. i am looking for about the settings source code recieved from the manufacturer of the tablet. we are trying to change them to hide some properties in the android settings. but this project is not compiling. do we need any other jars required to compile.

Comment: Is the android Settings project you are talking about available in android SDK samples? If not, then download some SDK samples (comes along with the SDK) and test them before you start making changes. This is always a good practice.